# Passport is forcing /login/callback nodejs

Tags: node.js, azure, authentication, azure-active-directory, passport.js

I set up passport for nodejs. I am using azure ad as well, and it is authenticating properly and rendering my landing page, but the problem is every time I try and click on a new link or enter a path in the url, it redirects me to that path, but with /login infront of it, so I am never actually getting to that new page - like this (localhost:3000/login/catalogue, instead of just /catalogue). Please let me know if anyone has had this issue before! Thanks :)

Here's my code. Thanks in advance!

```
   var SamlStrategy = require('passport-saml').Strategy;

passport.use(new SamlStrategy(
  {
    path: '/login/callback',

    entryPoint: 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/...',
    issuer: '...'
  },
  
  function(profile, done) {
    findByEmail(profile.email, function(err, user) {
      if (err) {
        return done(err);
      }
      return done(null, user);
      
    });
  })
);

app.post('/login/callback',
function(req, res) {
  console.log('inside /login/callback')
  //after login, goes here, but renders back to login/callback. then back here.
 res.render('index.ejs')
}
);

app.get('/login',
  passport.authenticate('saml', { failureRedirect: '/', failureFlash: true }),
  function(req, res) {
      console.log("inside azuread /login get passport saml")
     res.render('index.ejs')
  }



 );
```

Answer (score 1):

Check this out for reference:

- [passport-saml strategy implementaion in nodejs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47711518/passport-saml-strategy-implementaion-in-nodejs)
- http://www.passportjs.org/packages/passport-saml/

You might have to alter your routes code:

```
   app.get("/login",
    passport.authenticate("saml", (err, profile) => {
        // control will not come here ????   
        console.log("Profile : ", profile);
    })
   );
    app.post("/login/callback",
         (req, res, next) => {
            passport.authenticate("saml", { session: false }, (err, user) => {
                req.user = user;
                next();
            })(req, res, next);
         },
         RouteHandler.sendResponse
   );
```